# No executable found matching command "dotnet-./..dll"

Tags: asp.net, heroku, asp.net-core

I wrote an API in .NET Core that works great when I run locally, but deploying to Azure or Heroku gives me the same error in my logs: `No executable found matching command "dotnet-./..dll"`. I've included my project.json below, I'm not sure what other information would be helpful. Thanks!

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build" 
    }
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "Views",
      "Areas/**/Views",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "Tokens_monolith"
  }
}
```

Comment: You have spaces in the version for `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools`. Is that how your project.json actually is or is it just a typo here?

Comment: Yes, that was a typo, thank you.

Comment: That error sounds like you might not have the `dotnet` tooling installed on your server. How are you setting up the server?

Comment: For Heroku I'm using a dotnet buildpack that can be found here: https://github.com/noliar/dotnet-buildpack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue here was that the dll files in `.bin` folder were named differently than the parent folder name. I added this line to my `project.json` file:

```
"buildOptions": {
   "outputName": "whatever-you-want-it-to-be"
}
```

I re-built my app and everything seems to be working great. All of the dll file names were changed so I re-deployed to the server. Hope this helps!