# No executable found matching command "dotnet-out/CoreDemo.dll"

Tags: docker

I'm trying .netcore and docker.I wrote a [.netcore project](https://github.com/Uphie/netcore.demo/commit/b14e3b69e5a59bef6616ba9fba61d697af8dae1b)  and build a image.When I run it's container it gives this error:

[image: errors when my container fails to run]

My dockerfile shows below:

```
# 选择microsoft/dotnet作为基础镜像
FROM microsoft/dotnet:1.0-sdk-projectjson

WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY src/CoreDemo/project.json .
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . .
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# 容器启动后执行的命令
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/CoreDemo.dll"]

# 镜像维护者
MAINTAINER Uphie

# 容器暴露出的端口，可为多个
EXPOSE 5000
```

And I followed this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38950016/no-executable-found-matching-command-dotnet-dll) and edited project.json:

```
 "buildOptions": {
 "emitEntryPoint": true,
 "preserveCompilationContext": true,
 "outputName": "out"
 },
```

`"outputName": "out"` was added,but it didn't work. I don't know why this problem happens.

Answer (score 0):

I searched the files in the docker container and found that the complied dll was "out.dll" in "out" folder,which showed that "outputName" points to the target compiled dll. It's a gain.

Another problem I'm confusing is that without "outputName" specified,I get "app.dll" in docker with .netcore 1.0.1 but "CoreDemo.dll" in windows and linux with .netcore 1.1.0. Does the .netcore difference cause the problem?